# Q_INVOKABLE const getter returns undefined, non-const getter returns correct value - why?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have simple c++ class method:

```
Q_INVOKABLE const QString& getRiderTypeName(const int& riderTypeIndex) const;
```

with its implementation:

```
const QString& CumulativeSalesZoneModel::getRiderTypeName(const int& raiderTypeIndex) const   
{
    static QString result=QString();

    if(this->cumulativeSalesZoneData!=Q_NULLPTR)
    {
        result=this->cumulativeSalesZoneData->keys().at(raiderTypeIndex);
    }   // if

    return result;
}   // getRiderTypeName
```

and when is called from [QML](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-index.html), it returns *undefined value*. However, if I reduce [const](http://duramecho.com/ComputerInformation/WhyHowCppConst.html) operator, remove a [reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/returning_values_by_reference.htm) and remove [static](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-keyword-cpp/) declaration of `result` as part of returning value:

```
Q_INVOKABLE QString getRiderTypeName(const int& riderTypeIndex) const;
```

and its implementation:

```
QString CumulativeSalesZoneModel::getRiderTypeName(const int& raiderTypeIndex) const
{
    QString result=QString();

    if(this->cumulativeSalesZoneData!=Q_NULLPTR)
    {
        result=this->cumulativeSalesZoneData->keys().at(raiderTypeIndex);
    }   // if

    return result;
}   // getRiderTypeName
```

I get correct value. Why is so? I have tried this on several [Qt](https://www.qt.io/) versions on `Windows`, `Linux` and several embedded boards ([Raspeberry Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/), [Toradex Colibri iMX6](https://www.toradex.com/computer-on-modules/colibri-arm-family/nxp-freescale-imx6) and several others). On @Azeem request, I am adding relevant `QML` code:

```
Component.onCompleted:
{
    riderTypeName=cumulativeSalesZoneModel.getRiderTypeName(riderTypesIndex);
    console.log(riderTypeName);
}   // Component.onCompleted
```

Console outputs:

```
qml: undefined
```

if the first version of method is called and it outputs correct value if second version of method is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Revision # 1**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/61038922/1) (non-static/local data returning as const-reference):

```
const QString& CumulativeSalesZoneModel::getRiderTypeName( /*...*/ )
{
    QString result = QString();    // non-static/local object
    // ...
    return result;
}
```

**Answer # 1:**

On the C++ side, you are trying to return the address (reference) of a local variable i.e. `result`. It will go out of scope by the time that code block finishes its execution. So, you end up with a dangling reference. Using a dangling reference will result in [Undefined Behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Check your compile logs. You must be getting a warning like this:

> warning: reference to stack memory associated with local variable 'result' returned

Here's a sample program reproducing this warning: https://godbolt.org/z/pZBq7H

---

**NOTE**: The following part regarding returning references also applies to Answer # 1 above once the code is on the Qt MOC / QML side.

[**Revision # 2**](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/61038922/3) (static data returning as const-reference):

```
const QString& CumulativeSalesZoneModel::getRiderTypeName( /*...*/ )
{
    static QString result = QString();    // static
    // ...
    return result;
}
```

According to the Qt [Meta Object Compiler](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html#signal-slot-return-types-cannot-be-references) page, it states that (emphasis mine):

> **Signals and slots can have return types, but signals or slots returning references will be treated as returning void.**

And, to verify this, I've created this small [`test` project](https://github.com/iamAzeem/qtquick-test-class-methods) with multiple public [Q_INVOKABLE](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_INVOKABLE) methods. The QML is pretty straightforward. The returning string is shown as the `title` of the window.

You need to observe the files generated by the MOC.

The generated `moc_test.cpp` contains this part:

```
static const uint qt_meta_data_Test[] = {

 // ... code removed for conciseness ...

 // methods: name, argc, parameters, tag, flags
       1,    0,   39,    2, 0x02 /* Public */,
       3,    0,   40,    2, 0x02 /* Public */,
       4,    0,   41,    2, 0x02 /* Public */,
       5,    0,   42,    2, 0x02 /* Public */,
       6,    0,   43,    2, 0x02 /* Public */,

 // methods: parameters
    QMetaType::QString,
    QMetaType::QString,
    QMetaType::QString,
    QMetaType::Void,
    QMetaType::Void,

       0        // eod
};
```

As you can observe in the above code snippet (follow "methods" comments) that there are 5 methods. In the last portion, only the first 3 has return types i.e. `QString` but the last 2 return `void`.

And, observe the following generated method:

```
void Test::qt_static_metacall(QObject *_o, QMetaObject::Call _c, int _id, void **_a)
{
    if (_c == QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod) {
        auto *_t = static_cast<Test *>(_o);
        Q_UNUSED(_t)
        switch (_id) {
        case 0: { QString _r = _t->get1_RetByValue_NonConstLocalString();
            if (_a[0]) *reinterpret_cast< QString*>(_a[0]) = std::move(_r); }  break;
        case 1: { QString _r = _t->get2_RetByConstValue_ConstLocalString();
            if (_a[0]) *reinterpret_cast< QString*>(_a[0]) = std::move(_r); }  break;
        case 2: { QString _r = _t->get3_RetByConstValue_StaticString();
            if (_a[0]) *reinterpret_cast< QString*>(_a[0]) = std::move(_r); }  break;
        case 3: _t->get4_RetByConstRef_LocalString(); break;
        case 4: _t->get5_RetByStaticConstRef_StaticString(); break;
        default: ;
        }
    }
}
```

The first 3 cases in the `switch` properly set the arguments array i.e. `_a` but the last 2 cases do not.

The interesting thing here to note is the code in the first 3 valid cases, it is identical except the function calls e.g.:

```
QString _r = _t->get<...>();    // first 3 variations of get method
if (_a[0]) *reinterpret_cast< QString*>(_a[0]) = std::move(_r);
```

The returning `QString` is assigned to `_r` and then it is move-assigned to `_a[0]` from `_r`.

---

You can get the [project](https://github.com/iamAzeem/qtquick-test-class-methods) and run a debug session to observe this behavior yourself. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Azzem this is true, I've ugpraded the question, however the focu of problem is not C++ side, but why I get undefined value on QML side.

Comment: @KernelPanic: Because it is Undefined Behavior which is implementation-defined. You might get a garbage value or not - anything is possible.

Comment: @Azzem on C++ side it is not anymore, I've corrected it, like I said in my previous post.

Comment: @KernelPanic: You're asking what happens when you remove const-ref from the return value? Is that right?

Comment: no, I am asking why `const` version of method returns undefined value if it is called from QML side, and `non-const` version returns correct value.

Comment: @KernelPanic: Actually, that 's what I meant by removing const-ref from the return type. :) Can you show your relevant QML code? Because the reasoning is almost the same. With const-ref, a dangling reference is returned to a local variable. With a static variable and const-ref, there shouldn't be a lifetime issue but on the QML side, it might need a modifiable object. With the removal of const-ref, a modifiable copy is returned which is exactly what is needed. You can also try with `QString&` and check how it behaves.

Comment: If the result is declared `static` OR NOT, the first version of method returns `undefined` value in QML, the seond version of method (non `const`) returns correct value.

Comment: @KernelPanic: Right. So, the return by value works. Here's a relevant [thread](https://forum.qt.io/topic/23269/can-q_invokable-function-return-reference/2) with a relevant discussion.

Comment: I fail to see how this isn't an accepted answer. Accepted answer is unrelated to issue in OP